# Random Tab validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, tabs

I can't seem to find any examples that are exactly like what I'm trying to do, even though it would seem like the most common kind of example. I'm using JSP for my backend and hitting the database for validation each time a tab is clicked. I have 5 tabs, each with a form and since this is for editing the information in those forms, the text fields are already filled in. What I need to do is validate the information in those fields if it has been edited - which I have already - whenever a tab is clicked on but if the information is incorrect then the user cannot move forward. Now the tricky part is, the user can click on any of the 5 tabs and there is no particular order the user must follow when navigating the tabs. And that's where I having my problem. Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
    var $emptabs = $('#tabs').tabs();
    var selected = $emptabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
    //$('#tabs-' + selected).on('focusout', function() {
    //tabChange();
    alert('validating tab ' + ui.index);
    }
    });
    var firstName = $("#firstname").val();
    var middleInitial = $("#middleinitial").val();
    var lastName = $("#lastname").val();
    var suffix = $("#suffix").val();
    var gender = $("#gender").val();
    var dob = $("#dob").val();
    var ssn1 = $("#ssn1").val();
    var ssn2 = $("#ssn2").val();
    var ssn3 = $("#ssn3").val();
    var password1 = $("#password1").val();
    var password2 = $("#password2").val();
    var mrtlStsCd = $("#mrtlstscd").val();
    var strAddr1 = $("#straddr1").val();
    var strAddr2 = $("#straddr2").val();
    var city = $("#city").val();
    var state = $("#state").val();
    var zipCode = $("#zipcode").val();
    var zipPls4= $("#zippls4").val();
    var country = $("#country").val();
    var hmPhone = $("#hmphone").val();
    var cellPhone = $("#cellphone").val();

    $.ajax({
        async : "false",
        type: "POST", 
        url: "http://localhost/test/ActionServlet",
        data: { firstname: firstName, middleinitial: middleInitial, lastname: lastName, suffix: suffix, empgender: gender, dob: dob, ssn1: ssn1, ssn2: ssn2, 
                ssn3: ssn3, password1: password1, password2: password2, mrtlstscd: mrtlStsCd, straddr1: strAddr1, straddr2: strAddr2, city: city, state: state, zipcode: zipCode, zippls4: zipPls4, 
                country: country, hmphone: hmPhone, cellphone: cellPhone, step:1 },
        success: function(data) {
            var xmlDoc = null;

            if (window.DOMParser)
            {
               parser = new DOMParser();
               xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data,"text/xml");
            }
            else // Internet Explorer
            {
               xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
               xmlDoc.async = false;
               xmlDoc.loadXML(data); 
            }

            var status = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("status")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

            if (status == "ok")
            {
                var nextPageID = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("nextpageid")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                 alert('valid');
                $('#personalmessage').hide();
                $emptabs.tabs('select', selected+1);
            }
            else if (status == "errors")
            {
                alert('not valid');
                var errorElements = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("error");
                var errors = "";

                for (var x= 0; x < errorElements.length; x++) 
                {
                    errors += errorElements[x].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
                }

                $('#personalmessage').show();
                $("h2").html(errors);   
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#personalmessage').show();
            $("h2").html(errorThrown);  
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since no one answered my question, I got the help from a developer here. I guess no one here knew the answer or just didn't want to answer it. In any case, I'll be nice enough to share my solution. On the parent page the tabs script goes like this:

```
var $prevseltab = 0;
var $tabfuncs = {};
var $preventDefault;
var $bindTabs;
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();

    $preventDefault = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    $bindTabs = function(){
        $("#tabs").bind("tabsselect", function(e, tab) {
            $tabfuncs[$prevseltab](e,tab.index);
            return false;
        });
    };

    $bindTabs();    
});
```

On the child pages, it looks like this:

```
$tabfuncs[0] = function(e,currtab) {

    var firstName = $("#firstname").val();
    var middleInitial = $("#middleinitial").val();

    $.ajax({
        async : "false",
        type: "POST", 
        url: "http://localhost/test/ActionServlet",
        data: { firstname: firstName, middleinitial: middleInitial, step:1 },
        success: function(data) {
            var xmlDoc = null;

            if (window.DOMParser)
            {
               parser = new DOMParser();
               xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data,"text/xml");
            }
            else // Internet Explorer
            {
               xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
               xmlDoc.async = false;
               xmlDoc.loadXML(data); 
            }

            var status = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("status")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

            if (status == "ok")
            {
                 $('#personalmessage').hide();

                 var $emptabs = $('#tabs').tabs();
                 $emptabs.unbind("tabsselect");
                 $prevseltab = currtab;
                 $emptabs.tabs('select', currtab);
                 $bindTabs();
                 return true;
            }
            else if (status == "errors")
            {
                var errorElements = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("error");
                var errors = "";

                for (var x= 0; x < errorElements.length; x++) 
                {
                    errors += errorElements[x].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
                }

                $('#personalmessage').show();
                $("h2").html(errors);   
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#personalmessage').show();
            $("h2").html(errorThrown);  
            return false;
        }
    });
};

$(function() {
    $('#tabs').on('click', '#submit1', function() {
        $tabfuncs[0]();
    });
});
```